# Error: vhstack_dispatcher() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'dtype' and 'casting' after creating a new enviorment

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, osmnx

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a dict file, using pd.DataFrame.fromdict. A snippet of my code can be checked below:

```
path = r'...\file.json'
json_file = open(path)
raw_data=json.load(json_file) # 
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data, dtype=None)
```

I have been using this code for a while and everything seemed to work just fine. I had to upgrade my OSMnx package, and so I followed the documentation here: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, that suggested removing the enviorment and creating a new one.

After I did that I start to get an error on the code above saying: vhstack_dispatcher() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'dtype' and 'casting'. The complete traceback of the error can be checked in the image below:
[image]

[image]

I fear this error is related to the removal and creating of the new enviorment and I don't know how to fix this.

If anyone has any suggestion, I would be thankful.

**UPDATE:**
I solved this by deleting and creating a new enviorment.

Comment: Please provide your error tracebacks as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Also what version of pandas and numpy are installed now?